# Excel User Form validation on MultiPage control

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a wizard using a MultiPage control in Excel VBA.

It has 4 pages and I want to validate the data for each page.

For page 2, I'm validating textboxes, assuring they're not empty with the following code:

```
Private Sub validaPasso2()
Dim cCont As Control

For Each cCont In Me.Controls
  If TypeOf cCont Is MSForms.TextBox Then
    If cCont.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "caixa vazia"
    End If
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

However, this is checking all text boxes in the form and I want to check Page2 only. So instead of `For Each cCont In Me.Controls`, how do I express For `Each cCont In Me.Controls in Page2 only`?

Comment: Try reading this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/155374

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

 Dim cCont As Control



     For Each cCont In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(0).Controls

         If TypeName(cCont) = "TextBox" Then

             'DO STUFF HERE

         End If

      Next cCont



  End Sub
```

Found [here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/control-loop.htm)